# Critical editions of Portuguese literature

Tags: literatura, recursos

What are some good series of critical editions in Portuguese (and derivates) literature?

I have in mind something like Norton Critical Editions, where its not only the text and maybe a preface, but also historical context, reviews, comparative analysis and so on. Indeed, in Norton Editions, the text is often a smaller share of the whole volume.

Comment: Hello, welcome to our community! For reference to others, your question is on-topic according to [an old discussion on meta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/should-we-allow-reference-questions-on-main) - even if it's about references and not directly about the Portuguese language.